# Bootstrap How do i keep a background image in mobile for all grids?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, background-image

I have a layout with 3 grids, .row > grid1 grid2 gird3.
.row have a background image that affect all of the grids (which is what i want), but in mobile i want grids to be one below the other(and it does prety well)

```
@media screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:768px) and (orientation:portrait) {
     #mainBody > .container > .row > div > .content-box > div > div.grid-column-component.col-sm-6 {
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

problem is when in mobile the background affect only first grid, the others inherit nothing, i would like to keep the image throw all the grids. If not possible i would like to make the image

> cover & fixed

but not working either.

Do you guys have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys here is a quick fix answer for the problem.

```
@media screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:768px) and (orientation:portrait) {
 #mainBody > .container > .row > div > .content-box > div > div.grid-column-component.col-sm-6 {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y:auto
 }}
```

> overflow-y:auto;
>    this did the trick:)